# Calculating the difference between densities of coordinates in a python dataframe

Tags: data-science, density-plot

Imagine if you were trying to quantify an archer's ability to hit a target by distance. I want to measure the closeness/density of coordinates (if they were to be plotted on a graph, but I wont be doing that) in a large dataset. Then, I want to measure the change in densities/location of these groupings over different situations defined in the dataset.I dont know what I'd need to do in python to do this, and I'm really looking for the statistical guidance/packages needed to do so.

The 3 things I want to quantify

1. If I were to loop through different lists of coordinates, I want to be able to point out if there is clustering.
2. How tight the clustering is, what is its "radius" or its density?
3. How does the LOCATION and density change relative to situation?

This is a super large dataset. And the archer thing was just an example, I'm trying to create a sports statistic.